# Camera resets keyboard rotation before applying mouse rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having an issue with the free roam camera I'm trying to implement. The camera can be rotated via keyboard (only on the Y axis) and via mouse (on the X and Y axis) while holding the middle mouse button. With my current implementation, if I rotate the camera using the keyboard and the rotate it using the mouse, it remove any rotation done by the keyboard as soon as I hit the middle mouse button. Of course I would like to not do that... Code is below. Can someone give tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```cs
private void RotateCameraKeyboard()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
        {
            transform.RotateAround(transform.position, Vector3.up, -rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime * 30);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
        {
            transform.RotateAround(transform.position, Vector3.up, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime * 30);
        }
    }

private void RotateCameraMouse()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(2))
        {
            pitch -= rotationSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
            yaw += rotationSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");

            pitch = Mathf.Clamp(pitch, -90f, 90f);

            while (yaw < 0f)
            {
                yaw += 360f;
            }

            while (yaw >= 360f)
            {
                yaw -= 360f;
            }

            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(pitch, yaw, 0f);
        }
    }
```

Comment: In your RotateCameraMouse function, you do not take the camera rotation into account.  Add the cameras eulerAngles into your Yaw and Pitch calculations.  You probably dont want 0 for the z axis as well, maybe transform.eulerAngles.z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `RotateAround` (which in your case of using the transform.position as pivot is redundant anyway .. you could as well just use `Rotate`) additionally also add the according amount to your pitch and yawn.

I would simply generalize and use the same method for both inputs like e.g.

```
private void RotateCameraKeyboard()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
    {
        Rotate(-rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime * 30, 0);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
    {
        Rotate(rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime * 30, 0);
    }
}

private void RotateCameraMouse()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(2))
    {
        var pitchChange = rotationSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
        var yawChange = rotationSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");

        Rotate(yawChange, pitchChange);
    }
}

private void Rotate(float yawChange, float pitchChange)
{
    pitch = Mathf.Clamp(pitch + pitchChange, -90f, 90f);

    yaw += yawChange;

    while (yaw < 0f)
    {
        yaw += 360f;
    }

    while (yaw >= 360f)
    {
        yaw -= 360f;
    }

    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(pitch, yaw, 0f);
}
```